# Can I accomplish this query using recursion in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a main table, and a sub table. The Main table is the master list of parts, the sub table is the collective parts needed to build it. Each child part is linked to it's parent part through a ParentID.

The part or 'child' has a ChildID which points to it's own entry inside of the main parts list. We use this link to get it's price, as inside the subtable, only the ID is stored.

Very often, only parts that are marked as sub have their price stored. 
This query below works to roll up the costs for any entry, totaling up the sum of all the Prices inside it's list of sub items.

What I would like to do is, if the sub part is of PartType = master, then i'd like to roll up it's cost using this same query, and to use that as it's Price.

I understand this is a pretty complex ask, is this possible?

```
Select *, ifnull(
    (SELECT SUM(main.PricePer * Qty) 
     FROM sub inner join main on sub.ChildID = main.ID 
     where sub.ParentID = main1.PID), 
     0) 
from main as main1
```

---

EXAMPLE:

We have

Main Table Part 1 and 4 as master parts. Part 1 rolls up it's total cost accurately because all of it's sub parts are designated sub's. But part 4 has part 1 as a sub part. Meaning that it's reference to PricePer isn't accurate. It should use TotalCost for Part 1 when totalling itself, but to do this I would need to nest the query part1 used inside of the query for part 4 somehow.

```
ID | Name | TotalCost | PricePer | PartType

1    Part1  10.00       0.00       master 

2    Part2  0.00        6.00       sub

3    Part3  0.00        2.00       sub

4    Part4  4.00        0.00       master    //should be 14.00
```

Sub Table for Part 1

```
ParentID | ChildID | Name | Qty

1          2         Part2  1

1          3         Part3  2
```

Sub Table for Part 4

```
ParentID | ChildID | Name | Qty

4          1         Part1  1

4          3         Part3  2
```

Comment: What is your MySql version ? Recursive queries in MySql are supported starting from version 8.

Comment: 5.7, but I'd be willing to update.

Comment: What are the primary keys and foreign keys of the `main` and `sub` tables? I can help you if you can use MySQL 8.x.

Comment: @TheImpaler The primary key for the main table is it's ID field. And the primary key for the sub table is a SubID field that I didn't show in the example.

Comment: Sorry the main has no foreign keys, the sub's foreign keys are ChildID and ParentID. Which are both foreign keys of Main.ID